# Binding update on label

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I would like to bind a variable which if there a changes, it will automatically update the label.

```
var disp:String = "00:00:00";
var lb:Label = new Label();  //Add Label to an "ContentGroup" container.
lb.text = totalTime;
addElement(lb);

disp="00:00:01"; //New timing

BindingUtils.bindProperty(totalTime, "text", disp, "text");
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this in ActionScript?

Comment: Not sure about that, if using DispatchEvent will be more efficient than getChildByName? In what situation should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I want to clarify your question. You want to bind Label `lb` with `disp`, then later whenever `disp` change, `lb.text` change, is it?

1. Why don't use MXML (which perfectly matches with Binding mechanism) instead?
2. If you really want to use Actionscript, there are some points need your attention. Firstly, the "host" property has to be bindable (add `[Bindable]` tag on top). Next, `BindingUtils.bindProperty` should directly bind two values with each other. In this case, change to following code will work:

   ```
   [Bindable] public var disp: String = "00:00:00";

   private function initBinding(): void {

   var lb: Label = new Label();

   addElement( lb );

   BindingUtils.bindProperty( lb, "text", this, "disp" );

   }
   ```

By the way, I'm always avoiding using Binding if possible. Manually update properties in simple cases will save both file size and performance.

Comment: I see that how the bindProperty parameters is use. Thanks for the great tips, I will use getChildByName method instead.